# App crashing from listview implementaion

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I recently tried to create a custom row for listview.  I tried to do it off a tutorial but it crashes when I tried to change it so the rows work with what I want my app to display.  Error readout is at the bottom.

Also not related to the problem but I was curious if I am able to use imageId as my holder in the custom adapter class for each of the 3 images I want to be in the row or if they need to be unique.
    holder.img2.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

-----Homeactivitylistview.java-----------

```
public class HomeActivityListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList dogName;
    ArrayList dogID;
    public static int [] dogImages={R.id.dogimage};
    public static String [] dogNames={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity_listview);

        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dogImages));
    }


    public void sendProfile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  DogProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void NumberOne(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number one");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }
    public void NumberTwo(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number two");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }

    public void AddNewDog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     NewDogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

------------------- customadapter.java -------------------------

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(HomeActivityListview homeActivityListview, int[]     dogImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context=homeActivityListview;
    imageId=dogImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageId.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{

    ImageView img;
    ImageView img1;
    ImageView img2;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)             {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_single_row, null);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dogimage);
    holder.img1=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dog1num1);
    holder.img2=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dog1num2);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    holder.img1.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    holder.img2.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position],     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}

}
```

----------------------singlerow.xml--------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:id="@+id/dogimage"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/dogpic"
    android:onClick="sendProfile"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num1"
    android:background="@drawable/num1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="NumberOne"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num2"
    android:background="@drawable/num2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="NumberTwo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />
```

------------homescreen.xml------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivityListview
"
android:background="@drawable/screenbackground">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selectprofiletext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#2c7134"
    android:text="Select a profile or make a post:"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newdogbutton"
    android:entries="@array/dogs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectprofiletext"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add new dog"
    android:id="@+id/newdogbutton"
    android:background="#2c7134"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:textColor="#f3ca83"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="AddNewDog"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

------------------ Error readout ------------------------

> 04-07 14:06:40.998 2532-2532/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid, PID: 2532
>                                                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid:id/dogimage" (7f0d008e)  is not a
>   Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0d008e}
>                                                                                     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
>                                                                                     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageResource(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
>                                                                                     at
>   cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:57)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 04-07
>   14:07:23.942 2532-2532/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 2532 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a drawable instead of id which usually represents a view.Replace your dogImage with suitable resource such as `R.drawable.desired_name`.Then in your `getView()` use it as

```
holder.img.setimageResource(image[position])
```

or

```
holder.img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context,image[position]))
```

Comment: the first one is as I have it now, changing the drawable causes the images to show up but its not taking into account the sizes I had defined in single row.  Thus its making them look like they are zoomed in.  The 2nd solution you offered it wants some kind of expression on the Context part

Comment: setScaleType in your images

Comment: thanks never knew that was an attribute had to look it up but it worked out

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a drawable -

> ```
> holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogpic);
> holder.img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogpic);
> holder.img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogpic);
> ```

```
public static int [] dogImages={R.id.dogimage};
```

You are passing Id, you should pass drawable instead.

Comment: Thank you that worked, it did make the images really weird at least on the genymotion simulator.  Its zooming in on the images rather then just scaling them down to the sizes defined in the single row.